# React Native- How to separate a form into multiple pages submitting on the last page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, switch-statement, jsx

I have been trying to split a single page form available [here](https://gist.github.com/jqed-xuereb/7796d7516855717c05088e8914436dfc) , code for which is available here under into multiple pages in order to learn how to pass data from one page to the other.
I learned that this is to do with state handling and have been attempting to learn **Redux** to this end.

I have split the form into two files one containing two fields and navigating two the other file containing the screen with the submit button and 3 other fields. My main issue is getting data to pass from the first screen to the second so as to send a single payload on submit.

I have tried to do this by creating two reducers, one in each file, which contain the fields and pass on the data to the store by combining them and then sending that payload.

Is this correct ?  How would you approach this ?

Comment: This is using local state, what have you tried in regards to redux? Try getting redux set up to the point where you're able to dispatch an action from your component, update the store, and render our that updated value. The rest is straight forward. If it makes sense to keep it as one entity you can have one reducer, otherwise split it but that's up to you - I divide logically by data, not by what page the UI happens to present that data

Comment: @DominicTobias so you're saying you would implement a reducer file on its own and that would be called by both files ?

Comment: In your case I would have one reducer called `user`, since it all relates to that entity regardless of whether you split the form on to multiple pages (and yes I would have a root reducer that combines all the reducers (http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html), and then one called user in a separate file e.g. `reducers/index.js` and `reducers/user.js`)

Comment: @DominicTobias Could you elaborate as all the examples or explanation on how reducers work have been related to incrementation and I am still very green on how this is to be done.
Alternatively an example would be appreciated greatly or perhaps some resources on redux good practices.